# NSTableView, [table selectedCell] suddenly gives nil value

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I must have changed something to break this line of code in my project:

```
[table selectedCell] //it gives nil value
```

but the table row is selected (it's highlighted).
Table is cell based.

What could be the reason?

**UPDATE**: I've just seen in the documentation that this method has been deprecated in 10.10. But then what should I use to get the current selected cell?

Comment: I do not understand your problem. You say _selectedCell_ gives nil, but the _row_ is selected. A _cell_ is not a _row_ and a _row_ is not a _cell_. What do you want to achieve? Is your _tableView_  cellBased or is it viewBased ? It could make a difference. And that it is deprecated does only mean: It still works, but respect the future!

Comment: @HeinrichGiesen I understand that row is not a cell, and a row is not a cell. But what I meant is that there is a selection in the table, it's not unselected. The table is cell-based table. I know it should work even if deprecated, what I meant was that since it is now broken maybe it's a good occasion to change code.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. `-selectedCell` isn't specific to `NSTableView`; it's inherited from `NSControl` and isn't particularly useful to a table view. Individual cells can't be "selected", but rows *or* columns can.

Cells *can* be edited, however. Is that what you're trying to find out? Which cell is currently being edited? If so, you can use `-editedRow` and `-editedColumn`.

Otherwise, you can get either the selected row / row indexes or the selected column / column indexes, but row and column selection are mutually exclusive and either would encompass multiple cells. Since `NSControl`'s `-selectedCell` can only ever give you one cell, you'll never truly be able to get an answer that makes sense using that method on a table view. But of course only one cell can be *edited* at a time.

So is it *selection* or *editing* you're looking for?